# How to select the top 3 values from a group based on date and exclude duplicate value?

Tags: sql, sybase

If I three columns and 1 column has ID, 1 column has value and 1 column has date.  Example, ID column has ID1, ID2, ID3.  The value for each ID has a numeric value, say 1,2,3,4,5 for each ID.
How do I only get 3 results for each ID based on the most recent date descending.
I am using Sybase SQL.   Is there any way I can write this?

I tried to use Row_number() and rank() but I don't get to use either of those functions with my SQL tool.

```
ID  value   Date
1   3   20190511
1   1   20190503
1   5   20190401
2   2   20190520
2   1   20190514
2   4   20190503
3   1   20190516
3   5   20190415
3   3   20190402
```

Comment: You can use aggreate function, sum, avg..what do you want to do with it?

Comment: You mean you dont know how use `row_number()` or your db doesnt have it? What version is your db?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `row_number` try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM yourTable t2
       WHERE t1.id = t2.id
         AND t1.date < t2.date) < 3
```

So if one id have 3 or more older rows wont appear.

with row_number

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as rn
      FROM YourTable t1
     ) as t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
```

I assume you cant have multiple rows in same date. In that case you may want use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` and decide how handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery with `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date in (select top (3) t2.date
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id = t.id
                 order by t2.date desc
                );
```

Note that this assumes that the dates are unique.